# Code Completion in Multiline Strings in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, multiline

Whenever I try to write html code inside a multiline string using backticks in TypeScript, VS Code does not auto-complete the html tags.
For example:

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-property-binding',
  template:`
    <h1></h1>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
```

I have to manually write the header tags. VS Code does not provide auto completion.

Is there a way to add this to VS Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in your settings:

```json
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "typescript": "javascriptreact"
  },
```

see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-abbreviations-in-other-file-types

Answer (score 0):

You can unescape the the contents of the template string into another window by pressing Ctrl+Enter

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=plievone.vscode-template-literal-editor